# Trying to disable my Logic app via a HTTP Post

Tags: oauth, authorization, azure-resource-manager, azure-logic-apps, bearer-token

I am trying to disable my logic app via a Http post from within the workflow, but I can't seem to get the authorization to work with my AD.

It says I need the Authorization Bearer token header, but when I fill the information in the fields marked with the red star it always fails.

Either I input the wrong information or I am doing something else wrong.

[image]

Where do I get all the information for the fields for the OAuth to work?

Also isn't some of these for using against a web application like an API?
In that case how do I do this only in relation to the resource explorer API?

**UPDATE**
So i have tried to put it as a web application in my AD and that doesn't work either, is there ANY documentation about this anywhere??

Answer (score 2):

OK, so i found a workaround or maybe this is even the right way to do it.
Now using a HTTP Post Connector in Logic apps is probably the right way to do it when you have for example a API registered as an application in you AD that has the right permissions. what i did was:

**First:** Using/Created the Azure Resource Management Connector i didn't know excised, called "Invoke Recource Operation".

**Second:** After it propted you to login (with for example a service account), this layout is show to fill in the same inputs as in the request POST URL in the above connector.

Shown below:

[image]

This worked and disabled the LA perfectly.

Comment: This would be my recommendation, too, to use ARM connector instead of HTTP action.

Comment: Yeah i had no idea the logic app contained this, although it was pretty obvious in later thought i didn't see this in any documentation when searching for this specific problem. Its probably there but i just didn't find it.